# Quadrotor navigation in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner user of gazebo, and am confused how to navigate my quadrotor. I have used hector_quadrotor package.
I tried using `rosrun pr2_teleop teleop_pr2_keyboard` (after installing  `pr2_teleop` package), but it still gives error "Pr2_teleop" package not found. Is there some other easier way to navigate/control the quadrotor model?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247912/quadrotor-navigation-in-gazebo/) by [Siddharth](https://answers.ros.org/users/28449/siddharth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try running

```
rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
```

(To install : `sudo apt-get install ros-$YOURDISTRO$-teleop-twist-keyboard`)

It should work now. It will give additional yaw control. Or else, You can create a separate node which publishes `/cmd_vel` topic so that the quad can use to navigate.
If you can't create a node, publish the velocity using "`rostopic pub`" utility

```
rostopic pub -1 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -- '[0.0, 0.0, 0.3]' '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'
```

This will give linear vertical velocity.
To check: Use `rqt_plot`. Make sure that your initiated node publishes the `/cmd_Vel` topic to Gazebo model.

---

Originally posted by [Ajith kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26236/ajith-kumar/) with karma: 28 on 2016-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0